Zero forcing equalizer matrix
I am looking for an explanation of the matrix used in the Zero-Forcing equalizer, what its rows and columns represent, and why we focus on the middle row?
In the zero forcing we use $2N+1$ samples with $2N+1$ coefficients to get an output of
$z(k)= 
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\text{=1$\hspace{1em}$ for k=0} \\
\text{=0$\hspace{1em}$ else}
\end{array}
\right.$

Is there a reason you want to use a zero-forcing equalizer? It's typically a poor choice unless you have a channel with high SNR other than ISI--- what led you to this question?

@DanBoschen I'm having an important exam to pass that's why I read all the digital communication concepts

Ok that makes sense- what we do in that case since we can’t provide the exam answers for you (or similarly do homework problems etc) is that you provide us the explanation that you understand from your reading and studies to show your own research and clarify what specifically you are stuck on or don’t understand

See this help post on how to ask homework, quiz or test related questions: dsp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic What you could do is expand your question to include from your own studies your attempt at the answer and what part of that confuses you and we can then help fill in the blanks

@DanBoschen I will make another question as you suggested

@DanBoschen I was just wondering why the entire matrix was created and why each row represents the sum of previous or future samples

I understand that inversing the canal response we get the equalizer impulse response and the convolution of both response for a zero forcing equalizer gives a result called the all frequency pass which is a vector $z(t)$

No need to make another question just add those details to this question showing what you know and you studied and the additional insights you want
